# OS X app from jar: could not find or load main class when launched

Tags: java, macos, ant, jar, bundle

Upon trying to launch an OS X app I created from a jar file, nothing happens. When I then look into the .app contents and run the JavaAppLauncher, the terminal displays "Error: Could not find or load main class franky.GUI".

The steps I took are the following:

1) I created an executable jar file of my project by using eclipse. The package is named "franky", so when I unarchive the jar file again, there is a folder called franky with the java classes (including GUI.class, which is the main class). The external jars are also present in the top level directory.

2) I created a new folder with a build.xml file, and also the structure dist/frankenbot.jar and lib/appbundler-1.0.jar

3) the ant build file is created following this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html).

```
<property environment="env" />

<taskdef name="bundleapp"
         classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"   
         classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />

<target name="bundle-franky">
    <bundleapp outputdirectory="dist"
        name="Franky"
        displayname="Franky"
        identifier="Franky"
        mainclassname="franky.GUI">
        <runtime dir="${env.JAVA_HOME}" />
        <classpath file="dist/frankenbot.jar" />
        <option value="-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true"/>

    </bundleapp>
</target>
```

4) I would also like the final app to include JRE, so I made a bash_profile file containing the line 'export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)'. Before building, I execute 'source .bash_profile' in the terminal.

5) Finally, I bundle the app using 'ant bundle-franky'.

The build is succesful and the app is created in the 'dist' directory.  But as mentioned above, nothing happens when I click it, and running the JavaAppLauncher gives "Error: Could not find or load main class franky.GUI". I have searched a lot, and I also tried different mainclassnames/identifiers and such, just in case; but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!